# Trouble when submitting app to Mac App Store what should I choose my App ID Suffix to be

Tags: macos, app-store, app-id

Hi before this question gets down votes for not being programming related I would like to say that questions relating to problems with submitting apps to the mac app store etc are acceptable for S.O. as even though they are not directly related to programming it is a problem which is unique to mainly to programmers and therefore appropriate according to countless stack overflow meta answers.

Ok so anyway, like the question suggests I am not sure what my App ID suffix should be for an app meant for OS X when creating an App ID in the apple developer center.

This is as ideally it should be something like:

```
.com.yourdomainname.yourappname
```

Now I understand that it has to include .com and the name of my app but I am not entirely sure what is meant with .yourdomainname as I am not sure if this means I should enter the domain name of my website (I don't have a website) or what ever. I would be very grateful if someone would take their time to explain it to me and maybe give some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can use any App ID you want, the [reverse domain name notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) tries to make sure that there are no name collisions.

So basically Apple uses this notation for their own apps:

- com.apple.finder
- com.apple.mail
- Example for your case: com.companyname.appname or com.yourname.appname

I've also seen people use their countries top level domain instead of the `com`

There is nothing you can do wrong here, just try to keep the same notation for all your (future) apps.